# Why do I receive a "Voting corrected"?

Tags: support, up-votes, down-votes, votes

[image]

I have in no way abused this platform, or in any way encouraged others to vote my posts excessively.

I think I have worked hard and well earned the reputation here on blender.stackexchange.com over the last few months, and many of my posts are and have been a great asset to this Q&A platform as well as attracting audiences.

If there are certain users who particularly benefit from my contributions, then they should also be allowed to rate several of my contributions as useful!

I don't quite understand this. And can't accept it that way either.

If my efforts to make a meaningful contribution here are not valued, that would be a reason for me to withdraw from this platform.

Please for your assessment, what went wrong, because I see here rather a mistake in the system. For me, such an action is in no-go, and a reason for termination.

Comment: I did a quick check and it seems they have caught a “serial upvoter” who cast hundreds of improper votes. Crudely, the more active you are answering questions, the more times they voted for you. Moonboots, Chris, and myself were all hit harder than you, for example, and nobody active seems to have been missed. This adjustment is not a reflection on you and your contributions are valuable.

Comment: I do understand your disappointment.  About a year ago I reported some revenge downvoting.  When mods investigated they found that there was abuse and suspended the culprit for a week.  They also reported the incident to site admins who then discovered that I'd also been the victim of serial upvoting.  The net result was that the adjustment cost me more due to adjusting the upvotes than it gained me adjusting the downvotes.

Comment: But I moved on, it's a year later, and I laugh when I think about the amount of reputation that I was distraught over.

Comment: @MartyFouts I understand, I'm laughing about it again anyway. ;-) Even though I consider it partly a game here and the reputation points are just a fictional currency, I just want to be helpful first and foremost. Let's see what the future brings. Anyway, thanks for your support, understanding and wonderful contributions.

Comment: yes i also was hit by this and lost 20% of my reputation and i believe this was a mistake https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379345/alleged-serial-voting-reversed-but-no-suspiciousness-of-such-activity-taking-pla

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have not abused this platform or our voting system, your efforts have been noted recently.

Unfortunately there has been a site wide voting fraud and the site administrators have invalidated a large amount of votes by one individual user. Our site was hit particularly hard since he was more active here. These have happened from time to time and tend to be destructive on unsuspecting users, so they are not done lightly and great consideration is taken before comitting.

See [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) for more information.

You seem to have been one of the more affected users, but rest assured you have done nothing wrong, just a victim of bad behavior.

As a side note, you've been doing quite well, especially in the Geometry Nodes tag. I've been particularly interested in your answers. Keep up the great work and you will soon recover the lost rep.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful explanation and appreciation! However, this really hits me hard, since I personally only have RP left from the countless unpaid work hours that I spend to help others. Perhaps it would be better to put this work into more profitable projects in the future, rather than into a platform where one can become a "victim" of a user/algorithm at any time. For me, this is just a game: I solve puzzles, and get badges when I do well. But the game loses its appeal when the rules are not clear and some obscure system counts the points. ...my motivation is now quite dampened :(

Comment: Don't take it too hard, I know it can be discouraging, but it has little effect in the long run. It is more visible for users starting out but at the speed you gain reputation it will be meaningless in the greater scheme of things. It has happened to me on a few rare occasions since I've joined this site and quite frankly they aren't even visible in the reputation graph

Comment: PS: Just for the record, this answer was rated positive and marked as accepted by a legitimate user! ;-)

Comment: I was about to post about a single (! :) upvote being reversed. But the strange thing is, none of my posts have been upvoted recently (see [my reputation tab](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/65455/joachim?tab=reputation)). Has this individual been abusing the system for a long time and only recently been 'caught'?

Comment: Yes, I think many votes were not cast recently, as far as I can tell it goes some time back

Comment: I think the real question is why it takes so long until voting fraud is detected. How does the detection work? Is there a system or do mods just stumble upon them on chance?

Comment: it's supposed to be 24 hours but apparently it can take up to maybe 30 days coz even in my case where i did not gain 200 points in the past 7 days as of the moment i posted my complaint, i still lost 200 points. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379345/alleged-serial-voting-reversed-but-no-suspiciousness-of-such-activity-taking-pla

Comment: @tempdevnova: Certain processes are automatic, but sometimes more complex cases of serial voting may not be automatically detected; in those cases, when mods or staff notice it, then it's escalated to staff who then invalidate the serial votes (as explained in the linked MSE post).